# How to remove logic from view

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance

I currently have a few if statements in my view to determine which button to display to the user depending on their subscription status. I've heard that we should try keep the logic out of the views. Is there a better way of doing this (that might even load quicker)? I'm not sure how to incorporate javascript because I cannot show all the buttons to the user if their system doesn't have javascript.

```
<% if @user.subscription_status == 'active' %>
  <%= link_to "Downgrade to free account", cancel_subscription_path(@user) %>
<% end %>

<% if @user.subscription_status == 'canceled' %>
  <%= link_to "Reactivate", reactivate_subscription_path(@user) %>
<% end %>

<% if !@user.subscription_id %>
  <%= link_to "Upgrade", new_subscription_path(@user) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: use `helper` and use case statement instead of `if else` like `case subscription_status when 'active' .. when 'cancel' ... else ... end`

Comment: Thank you. What would the helper method return? eg The link text or a partial etc

Comment: it will return `link_to` what you did

Comment: do not implement it this way, the view must not check the values of a model, just send it messages

Comment: oooh yes also you can use the `active?` `cancel?` as an function so it will be helpful for you in model but case statement is always prefer in this case rathen than if elsif for code refactor

Comment: `case statement is always prefer` Please do not invent programming rules

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several alternatives.

But first:

- your current implementation is very bad: nobody except your object must check its internals.
- having several conditionals is not a big deal

So in your model, do:

```
def active?
  subscription_status == 'active'
end
```

and replace:

```
<% if @user.subscription_status == 'active' %>
```

with:

```
<% if @user.active? %>
```

If you want to dig deeper, look at decorators, like the draper gem.

If you want oneliners, use `link_to_if`, [see here.](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to_if)